# Flex horizontal tile list

Tags: apache-flex

I am using a horizontal tilelist in flex to display an image gallery with **only one item in horiz. tilelist being shown at a time**. I have next and previous buttons on both sides.

The problem is I want to display a particular item/image in that list when user clicks on a thumb image from another thumbimages tilelist at bottom.

I used **someTilelist.selectedIndex** property but it just selects that particular index in list, it does not show that particular item/image. **I want the list to *show* that particular image, not just *select* it**. Please take note that the horiz. tilelist shows only one image at time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
tilelist.scrollToIndex(index);
```